# Trouble calculating the moment of inertia of a solid cylinder with axis of rotation passing perpendicularly through the center mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

So im trying to calculate the moment of inertia of a solid cylinder of mass $M$, length $L$ and radius $R$. Here's a quick sketch:
[image]

my attempt has been like this:

I want to integrate a small element of mass $dm$ over the distance. so first I wanted to express $dm$ in terms of $dx$.
I figured that assuming uniform density $\rho =\frac{M}{V}$ I can express $dm$ like that: $dm=\rho \:\cdot dv$.

though that still not in terms of $dx$. so now I can express the small element of volume like that: $V_{\mathrm{cylinder}}=\pi\cdot \:R^2\cdot \:x$
such that: $dv = \pi \cdot \:R^2 \cdot dx$

so now, forming an integral $$I=\int _{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}}\rho \pi \:R^2x^2dx$$ I get this result: $$I=\frac{1}{12}\pi L^3ρR^2$$
and after expressing $\rho$ explicitly like that $\rho =\frac{M}{\pi R^2L}$ gives me a final answer of: $$I=\frac{ML^2}{12}$$

which is wrong. According to various sources the moment of inertia of a solid cylinder rotating about a perpendicular axis should be $$I=\frac{MR^2}{4}+\frac{ML^2}{12}\:$$

Can somebody show me the error of my ways? or at least, what is the pesky $\frac{MR^2}{4}$ and where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error occurred when you obtained the mass of the small element of volume (a disk, right?)

All the parts of that disk are moving in a circle about the axis of rotation, but each part has a ***different*** radius of curvature.  Just consider a short, fat cylinder.  Your integration lumps all that mass into the same radius.

One possible method to correct the error:

Find the moment of inertia of your elemental disk about an axis through ***the centre of the element***, parallel to the central axis.  Then use the parallel axis theorem to move that axis for the moment of inertia to one about the central axis.  Note that this introduces a second term to the MofI contribution for that element.

Integrate ***that expression*** for all the thin disks from one end to the other

Comment: thank you very much for the answer.but damn man im still not really sure how to go about it. how do I Find the moment of inertia of the elemental disk through its center of mass?

Comment: Try  https://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/2015/11/19/derivation-of-the-moment-of-inertia-of-a-disk/

Comment: what about calculating moments of inertia a square plates that are cross sections of the cylinder along its long axis? one such plate is passing through the middle and the rotsaton axis is going straight throug it and other plates are smaller in one direction, namely the direction of the rotation axis but same in other direction, of the dimension equal to L....so you could add up these plates?

Comment: o, well, the discs are easier to add up..